# Delete all messages from the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, curl

I want a cURL request to delete all the messages that I have stored in the MySQL database, so I wrote a query and when I enter it at the command line it displays an error. Here is my cURL request

```
curl -X DELETE "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/api/delete
```

Here is such an error in the terminal

```
{"timestamp":"2020-01-08T08:09:06.521+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet","trace":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet;
```

My code

```
@DeleteMapping("/api/delete")
    public String clearBase() {
        messageService.deleteMessages();
        return "Все сообщения были удалены";
    }
}
```

MessageRepostory

```
@Query(value = "DELETE * FROM chatMessages", nativeQuery = true)
    void clearBase();
```

Comment: There is already a `deleteAll` method which you can use. No need to write your own. Use that instead. If you really want the query you need to add `@Modifying` and fix the query it shold be `DELETE FROM chatMessages` no `*`.

Comment: Not an answer, but `DELETE *` is bogus SQL.  It should be `DELETE FROM chatMessages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify you will execute an update. 
Add `@Modifying` as a method annotation.

See this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Maybe  @Transactional is also advisable to use.